# How to filter data using window functions in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have the following data :

```
rowid uid time code
   1  1      5    a
   2  1      6    b
   3  1      7    c
   4  2      8    a
   5  2      9    c
   6  2      9    c
   7  2     10    c
   8  2     11    a
   9  2     12    c
```

Now I wanted to filter the data in such a way that I can remove the rows 6 and 7 as for a particular uid i want to keep just one row with value 'c' in code

So the expected data should be :

```
rowid uid time code
   1  1      5    a
   2  1      6    b
   3  1      7    c
   4  2      8    a
   5  2      9    c
   8  2     11    a
   9  2     12    c
```

I'm using window function something like this :

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("uid").orderBy("time")
val change = ((lag("code", 1).over(window) <=> "c")).cast("int")
```

This would help us identify each row with a code 'c'. Can i extend this to filter out rows to get the expected data

Comment: Can you clarify your requirement? Is it the case that for each UID, you want to keep only one row for each code, or is only for code 'c' that you need to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove only the lines where code = "c" (except the first one for each uid) you could try the following:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("uid", "code").orderBy("time")
val result = df
  .withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window))
  .where(
    (col("code") !== "c") ||
    col("rank") === 1
  )
  .drop("rank")
```

Edit based on new information:

```
val window = Window.partitionBy("uid").orderBy("time")
val result = df
  .withColumn("lagValue", coalesce(lag(col("code"), 1).over(window), lit("")))
  .where(
    (col("code") !== "c") ||
    (col("lagValue") !== "c")
  )
  .drop("lagValue")
```

Comment: On using the above code, when i do partitionBy("uid", "code"), the resultant dataset is incorrect as this gives the following result  :

rowid uid time code

Comment: apologies, missed uploading the entire comment..

So The resultant df is something like :

On using the above code, when i do 
val window = Window.partitionBy("uid", "code").orderBy("time")
df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window))

the resultant dataset is incorrect as this gives the following result  :

rowid uid time code rank
      1  1      5    a          1
      4  2      8    a          2
      2  1      6    b          1
      3  1      7    c          1
      5  2      9    c          1

Hence i loose out on the grouping on uid

Comment: @hbabbar You should try the full code, not only the first line: `df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window)).where(
    (col("code") !== "c") ||
    col("rank") === 1
  ).drop("rank")`

Comment: @hbabbar I don't see where the result you show me is wrong. It seems equal to your "expected" result, but just out of order. You can easily re-order it with `.orderBy("rowid")` or `.orderBy("uid", "rowid")`

Comment: Although the snippet was working as expected, there was a tweak in the functional requirement and we needed to cater that too. I included the "time" column in partitioning the window but in that case it also prints row 7 (which is not what we want). Any suggestions how to tweak this

Comment: @hbabbar I don't understand the new requirement. Why do you want line 9 but not line 7?

Comment: The 'c' here represents a conversion so the data in row 7 represent a conversion without any interaction with any digital channel so we need to filter that out

Comment: @hbabbar So there must be another column that specifies that it should be filtered out. With the sample data in your quesiton, I don't see any difference between row 7 and 9.

Comment: The difference between row 7 and row 9 is simply that the preceding rows (row 6) has code 'c' and (row 8) has code 'a' and thus we need to filter out such rows.

Comment: @hbabbar ok, so now there is a lag involved. I will update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121727/discussion-between-hbabbar-and-daniel-de-paula).

Comment: I'm afraid not, I was using the lag initially and the issue is the same that it is not able to recognize two consecutive 'c' and hence row 7 was not filtered. I know its a bit cumbersome to do back and forth for the same issue but I wasnt able to get the combination of these conditions correct

Comment: @hbabbar In my tests, row 7 was filtered