# Common terms between a window of rows

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am new to pandas and was trying out something. So this is the code for my dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['one two three','two three six','two five six','six seven five','five nine'], columns=['Numbers'])

print df
```

**Output:**

```
          Numbers
0   one two three
1   two three six
2    two five six
3  six seven five
4       five nine
```

I want to extract the common terms between each consecutive 3 rows ? so the output would be like this:

```
          common_Numbers
0          None
1          None
2           two
3           six
4          five
```

The first and second rows contain None since there are not atleast 3 rows. So is there any way to do it using some sort of window operation ? I have large number of rows>1M , so looping over every 3 rows is not an option.

**EDIT** : will it be feasible/efficient to do this in Apache-spark, preferabbly using PySpark ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas, here's one way to achieve what you want:

```
s1 = df.Numbers.str.split()
s2 = df.Numbers.shift(1).fillna('').str.split()
s3 = df.Numbers.shift(2).fillna('').str.split()
pd.concat([s1, s2, s3]
          ,axis=1).apply(lambda x: set(x[0]).intersection(set(x[1]).intersection(x[2]))
          ,axis=1)
```

---

Detailed execution:

```
In [28]: s1 = df.Numbers.str.split() 

In [29]: s1
Out[29]: 
0     [one, two, three]
1     [two, three, six]
2      [two, five, six]
3    [six, seven, five]
4          [five, nine]
Name: Numbers, dtype: object

In [30]: s2 = df.Numbers.shift(1).fillna('').str.split()

In [31]: s2
Out[31]: 
0                    []
1     [one, two, three]
2     [two, three, six]
3      [two, five, six]
4    [six, seven, five]
Name: Numbers, dtype: object

In [32]: s3 = df.Numbers.shift(2).fillna('').str.split()

In [33]: s3
Out[33]: 
0                   []
1                   []
2    [one, two, three]
3    [two, three, six]
4     [two, five, six]
Name: Numbers, dtype: object


In [35]: pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], axis=1)
Out[35]: 
              Numbers             Numbers            Numbers
0   [one, two, three]                  []                 []
1   [two, three, six]   [one, two, three]                 []
2    [two, five, six]   [two, three, six]  [one, two, three]
3  [six, seven, five]    [two, five, six]  [two, three, six]
4        [five, nine]  [six, seven, five]   [two, five, six]

In [36]: pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], axis=1).apply(lambda x: set(x[0]).intersection(set(x[1]).intersection(x[2])), axis=1)
Out[36]: 
0        {}
1        {}
2     {two}
3     {six}
4    {five}
dtype: object
```

Comment: This answer has better utilization of pandas operations. I like it.

Comment: I really like the step by step analysis

Comment: @Paulwitney glad this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas Data Frames have a [`rolling` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to implement SQL-like "window functions".

If you choose to use Spark (good for large datasets), then you need to use the [Spark SQL API](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html). Here's another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38872592/how-to-filter-data-using-window-functions-in-spark) addressing that specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution candidate:

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['one two three','two three six','two five six','six seven five','five nine'], columns=['commonNumbers'])

def getCommon(dfCommonNumbersColData):
    d = list(dfCommonNumbersColData) # May not be computationally efficient
    new_data = [None] * len(d) # Initialize list
    values = None
    for index, row in enumerate(d):
        if index > 1:
            row = row.split(" ") # Split the data
            next_row = d[index - 1].split(" ") # Last index
            next_next = d[index - 2].split(" ") # Last last index
            values = row + next_row + next_next # Join list to find common
             # Pass to counter to do a value_counts and grab the most common from the results
            new_data[index] = Counter(values).most_common()[0][0]
    return new_data # Return results

df['Common'] = getCommon(df['commonNumbers'])
df[2:].head(20) # Check the top values for accuracy
```

You'll probably have to find a way to handle 1M plus records but I think this would be a good starting point.

Obviously, this solutions misses "some" cases but the general solution is there.

Maybe it'd be a good idea to push those records to a database and query streaming data. <-That's a whole other problem